# How to create such kind of lighting? (pics inside)

Tags: lighting, softbox

How create such kind of lighting? (pics inside)

1)
[image: 1st image]
2)
[image: 2nd img]
3)
[image: 3rd img]

If possible, can u draw a plan (how it works, where to put the light sources?)

Comment: The three images you have posted all have different lighting. Please read [this post](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) on how to ask these kinds of questions effectively, and edit your post accordingly. This will help you get better and more helpful answers, and will be more useful in the future to others with the same question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First two photos are lighting setup on sideways (from shadows you can figure that out)

Now how to achieve this?
Using off-camera flash set up using RFs or keep some continuous light source on desired side.

For 3rd photo, it seems source of light is right in front of subject.